# GET request works in browser but not in POSTMAN or SOAPUI

Tags: rest, restful-authentication, postman

I have the following endpoint:
http://millennium.iwise.com.br:6017/api/millenium_eco/Tabelas_preco.lista

If I try to open via browser, it asks me credentials and then works fine - as seen on image below.

**user:** OData

**password:** 0d@t@123

[image]

If I send the same GET request using POSTMAN or SOAPUI I get 401 Unauthorized.

[image]

What I am missing here? Thank you in advance.

**UPDATE:**

I took the browser's header request and used the **same** in POSTMAN and I'm still receiving 401 Unauthorized. Is there a possibility of the endpoint's server is configured to reject all but browser's request?

[image]
[image]

Comment: I can see an NTLM Authorization header in your browser request. How do you configure your authorization in POSTMAN or SOAPUI? I see in POSTMAN you send Basic authentications.

Comment: @k.liakos Yes, you are right. I found someone with similar issue. Thank you for the tip. I will try to find a solution to do this authtentication in postman/soapui. If you have an idea, please share.

Comment: I found this https://www.soapui.org/oauth2/reference/ntlm.html for SOAP UI, but it requires an extra domain to use for NTLM challenges, which you have not provided. Are you aware of something like this?

Comment: I am not aware about it but I appreaciate your help. I will try to find a way. Thank you!

Comment: @k.liakos I'm trying to understand how the browser do this authentication. I do not send any domain information and the browser is able to handle the request properly. Do you have any idea? Perhaps something like "default domain"?

Comment: Never heard of NTLM actually until I came across this post. Google around, maybe you'll find something. One easy appoach would be to assume the same domain you send the request is also the challenge domain. Try it and maybe you'll get lucky.

Comment: @k.liakos Thank you and have a nice day.

Comment: @VictorViola - did you find a solution on your problem. I am facing the same problem. I can access a webservices in the browser with basic auth, but can't access the data when using Postman or any other client. - I am getting a 401 aswell.

Comment: Hi there @öbl. Yes, I found it but not using Postman nor SoapUI. I had to implement a Java class to handle the NTLM Authentication.

Comment: Sign out current account and restart postman worked for me.

Answer (score 16):

I got the exact same issue, requests working from the browser but not using postman.

Since postman syncs across devices, it maintains lot of cache info I believe. I clicked on my profile in the app and signed out from all the devices.
I then started the app, did not sign in , I clicked on the "continue without signing in option" which is a link close to the bottom on the sign in page. Then I was able to run the requests via postman.

I then signed in and things were fine via postman.

Note: I always had the SSL certificate verification Off in setting for the request.

Comment: My issue was that I had SSL certificate verification On in settings. Turning it Off worked for me.

Comment: Cleaning up cookies in Insomnia helped.

Comment: None of these worked for me the only thing was using the web app. Have a look at this answer by me https://stackoverflow.com/a/76750982/11306308

Comment: Sign out, sign back in worked for me. No other steps.

Answer (score 6):

I have also faced the same issue. It is working from my browser exactly when I provide the user name and password in the prompt window.

I resolved it by using the 'authorization' tab and select authentication type 'Basic Authentication' in the postman.

[image: Postman Screenshot]

Comment: That solved it for me as well! Also works when selecting Bearer Token as authentication method. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Sign out your current account and make sure checking `Clear local data` and re-login.

Answer (score 5):

I solved this problem by **replicating the exact network call** in postman. **NOT** by going into the network tab and manually copying headers etc. by copying the whole request into postman using a different way.

I highly recommend reading this article and giving this a try once.

[How to replicate requests from the Chrome Network Tab into Postman](https://medium.com/@tiboprea/how-to-replicate-requests-from-the-chrome-network-tab-into-postman-4ec6016ee18c#:%7E:text=Open%20your%20DevTools%2C%20select%20the,and%20finally%20Copy%20as%20cURL.&text=It%27s%20time%20to%20open%20Postman,your%20network%20call%20from%20above.)

Comment: That's the best approach to debug any request for this situatioon

Comment: I see, then all i can say is thanks cus you and someone else (on stack overflow) just save me stress of 2 days.

Answer (score 2):

Try to go Postman Settings > And turn SSL verification Off

It will allow you to send/ receive request/ response from unsafe URLs

[image: PostmanSettings]

Answer (score 2):

In my case it was due to I have a white space at the end of the url (invisible for me, copy and paste from the browser and may inadvertently added a white space there). Took me a while to find out. It seems like a small bug on Postman side.

Comment: This got me looking in the right place, I had a double slash in my URL. My variable ended with a slash, but also I added a slash in the address bar.

e.g. https://localhost:8080//api/some-resource

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue and didn't find any solution but it worked once I signed in from another postman account by deleting all the local data of postman. I do not have any idea about why that happened but it looks like it was some kind of setting that I had that caused this issue. I would recommend deleting local data and reset the postman setting if you are a beginner like me and have no idea what's going on.

Delete local data from postman: https://support.postman.com/hc/en-us/articles/4410785125271-How-to-remove-local-data

Comment: How do you delete all the local data of postman?

Comment: In my case i always got "nothing matches given URI" Error as below, but the same URI worked in chrome :


 `<body> <h1>Error response</h1> <p>Error code: 404</p> <p>Message: Not Found.</p> <p>Error code explanation: 404 - Nothing matches the given URI.</p> </body> `


For this i followed to delete local data as guided above and used my google account to login postman. Now it works better .

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue, solved it by using NTLM Authentication in postman. You can find it in Authorization tab in postman

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eRMAT.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Download the Postman desktop app and try from there.  The Postman website sending requests to localhost:5001 won't route correctly.  You could setup a port forward on your router to your local machine, but easier to get the desktop software.

I had the same issue above and this this approach worked.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion would be check the network tab of the chrome and check all the request headers, then, disable all the headers in the postman and apply/copy individual header. For me the problem was - I was passing Accept: "/" from postman, while I got to accept "text/html"

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Without even signing in i got the same error. I deleted all the history of postman and ran it again , it serves the purpose.

Comment: How do you delete all the history of postman?

Answer (score 0):

[Click on this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYYJT.png)

Go to settings->turn off ssl certificate

Comment: In my case, SSL was already off so it didn't help. But here's what fixed for me https://stackoverflow.com/a/76750982/11306308

Answer (score 0):

Mine was failing because I didn't have `www` in the url.  After adding the `www` to the url mine was successful using Basic Auth

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue. My GET request works with browser, but not POSTMAN (or INSOMNIA) if using bear token.

However when I changed to Basic Authentication, it works as normal.

I found the issue is due to my setting.py files (Im using DRF) not mention TokenAuthentication

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar error

[image]

The above was working completely fine on the browser tho. Basically, when I tried to visit the URL I will get the response on the browser but not on Postman or vs code thunder client extension.

I tried so many things like:

- Changing the request timeout to 0 (infinity)
- Toggling SSL Certifications.
- Clearing cache.
- Signing out from Postman and then trying without signing in.

None of which worked.

I think it has to do something with the firewall.

To fix this. What I did was to use the [postman web app](https://web.postman.co/). It works completely fine there. Post and Get request both. Give that a try.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to just go the vs code and right click the given link and make the visibility public. I promise it works.

Comment: You might want to [edit] according to [answer], i.e. describe the effect of what you propose and explain why that helps to solve the problem.